# SSIS Error in Connection Manager after modifying source file

Tags: excel, vba, ssis

Part of my package involves stripping the first row from an excel source in a script task before adding that data to a server in a data flow task.

The error message I get is `VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA`. I have my Excel connection manager set to the excel file, and have "first row contains column headings" checked. And of course, `The external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with the data source columns.`

The problem is: the first row doesn't contain the column headings until I strip out the first row in my script task. But since that doesn't take place until the package runs, when I click my connection manager for the excel file, it doesn't know - it shows the first row before I strip it out.

I already tried delaying validation, but it still fails.

Any ideas on how to fix this predicament? Is there a way to basically set the connection manager to refresh or something *after* my script task has been completed?

Thanks

Comment: When you configured the excel source you did it with a file that already had the first row removed?

Comment: @ChrisAlbert I just did that. I removed the first row, set up the connection manager, previewed it in my data flow. I just swapped it with a file without the first row removed, seeing now if it tricked it into working. The package is running right now, so I'll find out in a couple minutes

Comment: Where have you set delay validation? I would expect it to be set at both the Excel Connection Manager and the Data Flow Task

Comment: Just at the data flow task worked.

Answer (score 1):

Point your connection manager to a version of the excel file that you have saved with the first row already stripped out, for the purposes of configuring the columns in the connection manager.

Then have an expression on the connection manager, setting the connection string property to the location of the file after the script task.

It will then not be out of sync with the static, 'configuration' version of the excel, but it is still pointed to the excel file that you want at runtime.

Cheers